# OSMNx - Is it possible that I get shortest path from a node but no edge is connected to it?

Tags: osmnx

I'm working on a simulation and I want to log the distance of steps in a walking path.

Graph:

```
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(35.00843, 34.99174, 135.78775, 135.77495, network_type='walk')
```

The desired path is :

```
ox.shortest_path(G, 305371702, 305371770)
```

and I get the edges data using:

```
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, edges=True)
edges=edges[['u','v','length']]
```

But at some step in the shortest path I arrive to node 5327529704 and things become weird. While I get `True` for this node in `G.nodes()` the 'edges' dataframe is empty for this node:

```
edges[edges['u']== 5327529704]
```

and of course that I get an error for:

```
edges[edges['u']== 5327529704].loc[edges['v']== 5327529686].length.iloc[0]
```

How is it possible that there is no edge between two nodes in the shortest path? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've got it, I've tried using:

```
G = ox.utils_graph.get_undirected(G)
```

But that didn't solved it too. Figure I just needed to check twice, once were the starting node is on `u` and once when it is on `v`.

Not what I hoped to do but now I can manipulate the data to fit my purpose better.

Answer (score 0):

It all seems to work fine for me... here's a minimal reproducible code snippet:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# make the graph and get shortest path
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(35.00843, 34.99174, 135.78775, 135.77495, network_type='walk')
path = ox.shortest_path(G, 305371702, 305371770)
print(path)

# look up the length of a specific edge
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, edges=True)
edges=edges[['u','v','length']]
print(edges[edges['u']== 5327529704].loc[edges['v']== 5327529686].length.iloc[0])

# see that edge's attribute data in the graph itself
print(G.edges[(5327529704, 5327529686, 0)])

# get the lengths of each edge in the path
edge_lengths = ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, path, 'length')
print(edge_lengths)
```